# How to resolve System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: A connection with the server could not be established?

Tags: c#, api, .net-core

In my .Net core API project, when calling another API (which is stopped), I'm getting below error.

System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: A connection with the server could not be established

Instead of getting this error, I think it should return status code 503 (service unavailable) or 404 (not found), but I'm getting above exception. Please advice how to resolve this? My code is:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("apiBaseUrl");
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync("apiUrl");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to SO.

For your code to get a `503` or `404` response there would need to be a server at the URL you have specified. In your case there is no server at `apiBaseUrl` to return a HTTP status code. That would be the same for any URL that does not exist.

If you try a different URL e.g. `https://google.com/fake`, you will get a `404` because the server `google.com` exists to be able to send back a `404` to say the `/fake` part was not found on its server.

If you want to handle it then you can catch the `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException` and handle that accordingly.

```
try
{
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("apiBaseUrl");
    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync("apiUrl");
}
catch(HttpRequestException ex)
{
    // Handle the exception here
}
```

If you think of it like a postal address. If you write to a random address that doesn't exist then you you will get your letter back from the post office with an exception saying "no such address" - which is equivalent to your exception above.

However, if you write to a real address but to a person that doesn't live there then you will get your letter back from the residents of that address saying "No such person at this address" which is the same as a `404`.

In the example, the post office is the .NET Framework/HttpClient class and the residents at the real address are a web server.

Comment: You are correct. I was expecting 404/503 in an incorrect scenario. When the application is up & running (in localhost) & used an incorrect api method name, it returned 404, instead of an exception. Thank you very much.